# discord.js v13 slash commads everyone ping not notice

Tags: discord.js

I ping everyone with the slash command, but the @everyone mark is visible, but there is no notification.
Here is my code.

```js
client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
    data: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: '@everyone',
        embeds: [embed]
      }
    }
});
```

I'm Korean, so I wrote a translator.

Comment: do you have `@everyone` pings allowed in a bot? you can turn it off when creating client so bot doesn't ping `@everyone`, which may be the case

Comment: Yes, but don't get notifications only from the slash command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `@everyone` **doesn't** actually ping from a `Slash Command` is because they use webhooks and webhooks are not allowed to ping `@everyone` regardless of your permission setup, so it's not possible to ping in slash command

> *However there is a workaround*

you can use `CommandInteraction#reply` method to reply an ephemeral response that will only be visible to the person who executed the command
and after that use `TextChannel#send` method to normally send the message with ping and to get the channel use `CommandInteraction#channel`
This will ping `@everyone` provided your bot has permissions to ping and you are not disabling it in the `ClientOptions` or the message payload